How can I completely reset or wipe a Linux device programmatically?
I’m working on a function that needs to completely reset a virtual or physical host, bringing it back to its original state.
This would be similar to the "Reset" or "Wipe" feature available on Windows and macOS, which have APIs that handle the reset process. I need a  similar function on Linux, whether it's through a command, script, or API that can be triggered programmatically.
Here’s what I’m specifically looking for:

A command or script that can be executed to completely wipe the system, effectively returning it to a factory reset state.

Any platform APIs or system utilities on Linux that are designed for this purpose.

Best practices or security considerations when performing such an operation.


Does Linux have a built-in method for this, or would I need to script the necessary steps (like deleting partitions, resetting configurations, etc.) myself?
Any advice or references to existing solutions would be greatly appreciated!
Additional Context:
The function should work across Linux distributions. The process should be fully automated, with no need for manual intervention once started.

Different distributions have wildly different management tools - from none to quite complex ones. Target one distribution, and look into that. That said - what is a reset? What packages to keep? You'll probably have to write some shell scripts - and even that seems daunting. I'd go for reinstall.

There are tons of tutorials on how to integrate clonezilla with grub. Pro: It's distribution independent; con: you need to reapply updates since the last image was taken.

From a security perspective, even without a complete solution, you should already have a way of "cleaning up" remote/mobile devices using something run from your config management solution or EDR solution. This could be anything from scripts that zero out files, or encrypting partitions that require an unlock key. Hosts under your physical control probably don't need this for security or any other reason.

TL;DR This is not straightforward or practically feasible. What can be done is to define an initial desired system and reset its clones/childs to that initial state, it cannot be done in a general manner. What windows actually does (I don't know internals of macOS) is to boot a recovery standalone system to apply a default image, "as it had the original ISO".
There is no such functionality OOB in Linux. You could prepare such Linux systems with 1-day operations set of packages, settings, trusted root CAs, etc. and then perform a snapshot at filesystem level for bare metal. A virtual machine could perform a snapshot by its hypervisor, but it can also be done at filesystem level. As instance: LVM's LV snapshot, btrfs, XFS, etc. allow this (I know LVM is not strictly a 'FS').
Still, I do not recommend that path, I would go with PXE-based reinstall for bare metal, and Virtual machine templates provisioning. Both of these methods can be automated. Then perform an Ansible role for day 1 operations/customizations.
What you propose, for example, performing a reset with an Ansible role/playbook that works with any given system:
File system layout
What is a standard Linux system? From FS perspective, there is not such a 'standard' layout. You should define your initial desired business state of your systems, this may vary a lot between a bare metal and virtual instance. A beefy Tomcat may need a big /opt or /var partition/extra disk. But DNS server can live with little storage and default root filesystem.
A basic file system tree also has its permissions, and they can vary between Linux variants.
Packages
To reset to a default subset of packages, you can uninstall those not included in the default installation of a given distro. This will differ between distros and their major versions. Moreover, some distros provide specialized sets for a purpose: minimal, virtualization host, default, etc. To do this correctly, dnf/apt transaction log has to be parsed to know the true initial set. You still don't know if there are manually uncompressed packages around /var/local or /opt (please use /opt!).
Already installed packages
Now that you do not have extra packages, an admin may have reconfigured settings for some of the still installed packages, or their file permissions. Some examples: https://askubuntu.com/questions/66533/how-can-i-restore-configuration-files https://askubuntu.com/questions/66533/how-can-i-restore-configuration-files. And this must be done for virtually every package.
Users, kernel modules, sysctl, admin installed systemd units
All the above that is not from default install must be removed.
Missing things
And I am sure I am missing more like machine UUID reset, DHCP client desired IP, NIC config, soft eth bridges, package manager cache, domain join, trusted root CA, etc.
